# Brackets auto tag completion like dreamweaver?

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++, config, dreamweaver, adobe-brackets

I've just about had as much as I can stand with Brackets, and NPP isn't much better. I'm so used to coding in Dreamweaver that I have become very accustomed to Adobe's auto tag completion - for example - 
When I type

```
<div>
div content
misc. stuff
etc
</   (at this point, dreamweaver will complete the </div> tag)
```

In brackets, as soon as I type

```
<div>
```

it will automatically turn it into:

```
<div></div>
```

with the cursor in the middle, to insert content between the opening and closing tags.
Notepad++ will do neither of the above, unless I go into settings>preferences and turn on tag autocomplete, where it will do the exact same thing as brackets.

I absolutely hate this, I love the way Dreamweaver completes their tags but I don't like Dreamweaver in general. Is there a setting for this type of auto-completion in Brackets or Notepad++ that I may have overlooked? I've spent literally hours looking for a solution to this, everything from editing backets' JSON file to trying different HTML editors to almost throwing my G** D*** laptop against a wall from infuriation.

Is there a setting I can change, or a specific line of code I can add to Brackets' config.json file? If not, if you know of another program that has dreamweaver style tag closing, please please PLEASE let me know, I've been desperately looking for something to replace it!

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Brackets you can get that behavior by adding this line to your preferences JSON file:

```
"closeTags": {"whenOpening": false, "whenClosing": true, "indentTags": [], "dontCloseTags": []}
```

To edit your preferences file, choose *Debug > Open Preferences File* from the menu. If the file is currently blank, be sure to wrap the above line in `{}`s.

For more details, check out the [full list of Brackets preferences](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences).